# A prolog program that reflects people sitting at a round table

Tags: prolog

I've got a prolog homework to do: There are 5 persons sitting at a round table of different nationalities (french, english, polish, italian, turkish). Each of them knows only one other language other than their own. They sit at the round table in such a way that each of them can talk with their 2 neighbors (with one neighbor they talk in their native tongue and with the other in the single foreign language they know). The english person knows italian, the polish person knows french, the turkish person doesn't know english. The question is what foreign language does the turkish person know?

I've done something using only clauses and predicates but I reached a dead end, teacher suggested the easiest way would be to use lists.

Any thoughts on what that list would contain or any code ideas at all?

UPDATE (weak logic code):

```
    predicates
knowTheLanguage(symbol,symbol)  
knowNotTheLanguage(symbol,symbol)
isNeighbor(symbol,symbol,symbol,symbol)

aTheory(symbol,symbol,symbol,symbol) 
anotherTheory(symbol,symbol,symbol,symbol)

    clauses
knowTheLanguage(englishman,italian).
knowTheLanguage(polishman,franch).

%native tongues
knowTheLanguage(englishman,english).
knowTheLanguage(frenchman,franch).
knowTheLanguage(polishman,polish).
knowTheLanguage(italianman,italian).
knowTheLanguage(turk,turkish).


knowNotTheLanguage(turk,english).

aTheory(centralPerson, languageCntrlPers, personOnOneSide,languagePrsnOnOneSide) if knowTheLanguage(personOnOneSide,languageCntrlPers)
                                                                            and not( knowTheLanguage(centralPerson,languagePrsnOnOneSide))
                                                                            and not(knowNotTheLanguage(centralPerson,languagePrsnOnOneSide)).
anotherTheory(centralPerson, languageCntrlPers, personOnOneSide,languagePrsnOnOneSide) if knowTheLanguage(centralPerson,languagePrsnOnOneSide) 
                                                                            and  not( knowTheLanguage(personOnOneSide,languageCntrlPers))
                                                                            and not(knowNotTheLanguage(centralPerson,languagePrsnOnOneSide)).

isNeighbor(centralPerson, languageCntrlPers, personOnOneSide,languagePrsnOnOneSide) if aTheory(centralPerson, languageCntrlPers, personOnOneSide,languagePrsnOnOneSide)
                                                                        or
                                                                        anotherTheory(centralPerson, languageCntrlPers, personOnOneSide,languagePrsnOnOneSide).
```

Update - programming environment : turbo prolog 2.0 '86,'88 by Borland, also I'm a complete beginer in prolog, so... I'd apreciate at least a full sketch of the program and explanations outside of the code body. I process things slow :D

Comment: You should show what you tried, so we can help you

Comment: i'll try but it involves translating the names in order to make sense in english, so maybe tonight

Comment: query your instructor if you are allowed to use CLP(FD). That would be the easiest and most efficient way to solve...What Prolog are you using? the syntax you show isn't standard...

Answer (score 1):

You can work with cyclic list, try this code to understand.

```
t :-
    L = [1,2,3 | L],
    my_write(5, L).

my_write(0, _).
my_write(N, [H | T]) :-
    write(H), nl,
    N1 is N - 1,
    my_write(N1, T).
```

Cyclic list may be very usefull for you.

Describe what are the elements of the list, then what  is the constraint for the languages

EDIT : Here is my solution, works with SWI-Prolog :

```
% @arg1 : list of nationalities around the table
% @arg2 : list of persons
dinner(Languages, Table) :-
    length(Languages, Len),
    length(Table, Len),

    % set Natianalities and languages
    init_1(Table, Languages, Languages),

    % create cyclic list
    % works with SWI-Prolog
    append(Table, L, L),

    % set languages constraint
    init_2(Len, L).

init_1([], [], []).

init_1([person(N, L) | T], Nations, Languages):-
    select(N, Nations, New_Nations),

    % problem specific
    (   N = english
    ->  L = italian
    ;   N = polish
    ->  L = french
    ;   true),

    select(L, Languages, New_Languages),

    % problem specific
    (   N = turkish
    ->  L \=  english
    ;   true),

    init_1(T, New_Nations, New_Languages).

% persons speaks with theirs two neighbors
init_2(Tr, [person(_N1, L1), person(N2, L2), person(N3, L3) | T]) :-
    Tr > 0,
    member(N2, [L1, L3]),
    Tr1 is Tr - 1,
    init_2(Tr1, [person(N2, L2), person(N3, L3) | T]).

init_2(0, _).
```

Comment: I'll return with some feedback later, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: and after that Phantasme Punk did the translation job that should be an answer???

Comment: I hope this answer could help him. I solve the problem with a cyclic list.

Comment: cyclic terms are an esoteric feature (more often bugs), and some Prolog can't handle it (loops and/or crash, I don't know about visual Prolog, seems that's selected). I don't think your solution (whatever) would be similar to the code posted.

Comment: Phantasme Punk asks for a help with lists. I know only SWI-Prolog and I did'nt know that some Prolog couldn't use cyclic lists. I think that CLP(FD) is not what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would solve such a puzzle using constraints, but that would probably be too advanced for your homework. So, instead of using constraints to restrict the search space, we have to use tests to check whether the solution is feasible.

You will need to work with two lists, say `People` and `Languages`. Each element of the lists corresponds to one seat at the table. Both lists can have the same domain, `[f,e,p,i,t]`. The semantics of the domain should be clear.

To generate the solution, you first set up the lists, then instantiate the lists and check whether the instantiation fulfils your constraints:

```
puzzle(People, Languages) :-
    Domain = [f,e,p,i,t],
    length(People, 5),
    length(Languages, 5),
    % symmetry break:
    People = [f|_],
    % instantiate People
    people(People, Domain),
    % instantiate languages and check constraints
    languages(Languages, People, Domain).
```

Note that the first element of list `People` is set to `f`. This is to rule out symmterical solutions, which will otherwise be returned since the table is round. Without this restriction, each solution would have four additional symmetrical solutions.

Try to come up with your own solution before reading on... :-)

The list `People` is instantiated first. We need to take care that each element appears only once:

```
people([], []) :- !.
people([P|RestP], Domain) :-
    delete(P, Domain, RestD),
    people(RestP, RestD).
```

Your dialect of Prolog may have `select/3` instead of `delete/3`.

When instantiating the list `Languages`, we also check that the puzzle constraints are not violated:

```
languages(Languages, People, Domain) :-
    Term =.. [[]|People],
    languages0(Languages, People, Term, 1, Domain).
languages0([], _, _, _, _) :- !.
languages0([L|RestL], [P|RestP], Term, I, Domain) :-
    delete(L, Domain, RestD),
    L \= P, % language needs to be foreign
    check_l(P, L),
    check_n(L, I, Term),
    I1 is I+1,
    languages0(RestL, RestP, Term, I1, RestD).
```

Again, each element can only appear once.

`check_l` checks the constraints regarding the foreign languages:

```
check_l(e, i).
check_l(p, f).
check_l(t, L) :- L \= e.
check_l(f, _).
check_l(i, _).
```

`check_n` ensures that language and nationality of either left or right neighbour match:

```
check_n(L, I, Term) :-
    ( I == 1 -> NL = 5 ; NL is I-1 ),
    ( I == 5 -> NR = 1 ; NR is I+1 ),
    ( arg(NL, Term, L) ; arg(NR, Term, L) ).
```

There are two solutions:

```
?- puzzle(P, L).
P = [f, e, i, t, p]
L = [e, i, t, p, f]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
P = [f, p, t, i, e]
L = [e, f, p, t, i]
Yes (0.01s cpu, solution 2, maybe more)
No (0.01s cpu)
```

Comment: return false to me

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when modelling a problem, it's important to identify a compact representation, eliminating irrelevant details. Here having, for instance, `polishman` and `polish` is useless. We can agree that `polish` stands for *both* the man and the language.

I sketch the solution, please fill in the ellipsis, adding the constraints:

```
puzzle(L) :-
    L = [P1,P2,P3,P4,P5],
    cadj(P5,P1,P2),
    ...
    member(p(english, italian), L),
    member(p(french,  _ ),      L),
    ...
    \+ member(p(turk, english), L).

% constrain adjacents
cadj(p(Pl, Ll), p(P, K), p(Pr, Lr)) :-
    P = Ll, K = Pr ; P = Lr, K = Pl.
```

p/2 stands for the man and the language he knows.
cadj/3 says that if the man at left knowns my language, I must know the language of the man at right, or viceversa.

To get the required language, try

```
puzzle :-
    puzzle(L),
    memberchk(p(turk, T), L),
    writeln(T:L).
```

There are more solutions, but the language `T` is consistently constrained to a single value...

Comment: puzzle is defined in the predicates section as puzzle(symbol)?  none of the answers follow the structure that I posted, and it's confusing for me. it would be nice if I knew what (or if I need) in the domains,predicates, clauses and goal sections.

Comment: I see your point, but as you can argue from my answer, I don't have Turbo Prolog available. You should devise the appropriate 'declarations' it requires (does it have member/2? I can't  remember this detail from more than 20 years ago...). Compiler apart, in your question I can't spot the 'engine' for solving, just the data. Then I propose such 'engine' in plain ISO Prolog

Comment: what I do with the code in my post is compile it and the the goal objective appears then I input the same parameters as defined in the clauses section and then... the output is Yes, or No so.... that's how it runs... not sure if that clarifies anything.

Comment: But why are you using that old Prolog, instead of one the many good available alternatives? Does your teacher require it?

Comment: why not? :)) ... this is the teacher's requirement, the answers could be more clear but maybe that's not your intent.

Comment: You can see yourself. You got 3 answers to your question but Turbo Prolog can't run them...Maybe you could tag [turbo-prolog] and untag [prolog]